# C# XMLWriter - non-standard XML elements

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmlwriter

I have some XMLWriter code that I need to modify:

```
XmlWriter messageWriter = XmlWriter.Create(strbuilder);
messageWriter.WriteStartDocument();

//Add this line below
messageWriter.????  (@"<!DOCTYPE message SYSTEM "work_request_20.dtd">");

messageWriter.WriteStartElement("message");
messageWriter.WriteAttributeString("message_id", id.ToString());
messageWriter.WriteAttributeString("message_dt", Lb.TestDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt"));
```

Unfortunately, so far, no matter which method I use connected to the XMLWriter it does not like the "<" ">" or "!" characters.  If I use the StartElement or similar I believe it will add the "< >" for me.

If I take all three characters out (<, >, !) then it tells me "  Message=Token Text in state Document would result in an invalid XML document."

Please advise on how to make this work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You want [`WriteDocType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.writedoctype(v=vs.110).aspx). Used as below:

```
messageWriter.WriteDocType("message", null, "work_request_20.dtd", null);
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EN0Bnn) for a demo.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer I needed.  It is:  xmlwriter.WriteRaw

This is a special case and not a "real" xml file per se, but it is in a basic XML format.  But for this special case I needed to write non-standard XML and it looks like "WriteRaw" will do what I need.

Comment: It's either XML or it isn't.  Once you start using non-standard practices, you'll find that interoperability with other systems or applications fails (probably years after you left the company).